# regex to remove last two letters in a number and word string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to only match few ID's where there are either one or two alphabets at the end

Example:

ny12345**d**  ---to be matched

ny12345**dc** -- to be matched

ny12346**T01**  --not to be matched

ny12346**dfA**  --not to be matched

ny12345 ------not to be matched

so far I came up with this

```
/[^0-9]*$/g
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bjBWkA/1/   (oops `ny12346dfA` was not copied...) Changed in this one: https://regex101.com/r/bjBWkA/2/

Comment: what about `\d[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$` match a digit, then 1 or two letters before the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KL77Cl/1)

*Details*:

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is an ASCII letter immediately to the left of the current location
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` - one or two ASCII letters at
- `$` - end of string.

A capturing group approach:

```
(?:[^a-zA-Z]|^)([a-zA-Z]{1,2})$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R0lAvy/1). Here, `(?:[^a-zA-Z]|^)` is a non-capturing group matching either a char other than an ASCII letter or start of string, and `([a-zA-Z]{1,2})$` is similar to the pattern described above, with the letters captures into Group 1.

**NOTE**: If you want to make sure there is a digit before the last one or two letters, you need

```
(?<=\d)[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$
(?<=[0-9])[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$
\d([a-zA-Z]{1,2})$
[0-9]([a-zA-Z]{1,2})$
```

Here, `\d` or `[0-9]` matches any digit and `(?<=\d)` is a *positive* lookbehind that requires a digit to appear immediately to the left of the current location.

Comment: Nice negative lookbehind :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Online regex demo is: [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I6qAlr/1)

```
[^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]{1,2}$
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking if at last of line anything apart from alphabets is there followed by 1 or 2 alphabets then match that string.